# Unable to cross-assemble ARM 32-bit assembly program on 64-bit ARM (AArch64) Ubuntu

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-20.04

I am unable to execute my assembler program on Ubuntu 20.04 64bit installed on my Raspberry Pi 4.

I built the assembler code with

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-as -o testas.o testas.s
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o testas testas.o
```

Typing `./testas ; echo $?` into the terminal gives me as a result
`bash: ./testas: No such file or directory`.

The content of the code:

```
.global main

main:
mov r0,#1
bx lr
```

Comment: Are you sure you typed `./testas` and not `.testas` as the error message indicates?  Note also that assembly is *assembled,* not *compiled.*  And lastly, note that your second command directly generates a binary from the assembly source file, negating any need to first generate an object file.

Comment: Did you run `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` and `./testas` on an x86-64 desktop?  That ARM assembly code is 32-bit, not ARM64 aka AArch64, so IDK what you mean by "64-bit Ubuntu".  Do you really have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on your RPi?  I get a similar `/lib/ld-linux.so.3: No such file or directory` message if I try to run the output of `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` on an x86-64 Ubuntu desktop I have.  (Because I have qemu-binfmt installed, so it's trying to run QEMU on it).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. yes i have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my RPi. Is there any way to execute 32bit assembly code on arm64?

Comment: Ok, that rules out the x86 mistake.  You might need some kind of gcc-multilib package installed, IDK.  Use `file testas` and/or `ldd testas` to see what files it's looking for.  Or `strace ./testas`

Comment: ldd testas says : "not a dynamic executable"

Comment: Ok, that's surprising, I guess maybe your `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` is configured to make static executables by default?  That's not how native GCC on a normal Ubuntu is set up, but this is a cross-compiler targeting 32-bit ARM so it could be anything.

Comment: strace ./testas gives : No such file or directory.

Comment: @PeterCordes Could be a wrongly configured dynamic linker path.  This causes the symptom OP experiences; “no such file or directory” refers to the dynamic linker.

Comment: @fuz: Good idea, but ldd saying "not a dynamic executable" means there is no ELF interpreter at all, fully statically linked, so we can rule out that problem for this case.  (Assuming the `ldd` output still means the same as in [What's the difference between "statically linked" and "not a dynamic executable" from Linux ldd?](//stackoverflow.com/q/61553723)). Perhaps there's a binfmt-misc config for emulating 32-bit binaries for some reason, and it's misconfigured or not fully installed? But no, that would have given `strace` something to latch on to.  We need `file` and `readelf -a` output

Comment: @fuz: The OP changed that; after seeing your comment I checked to make sure it was the OP's edit that changed that before making my own.